# Unable to shoot bullets in pygame while making a 2 player space invaders game

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am making a 2p Space Invaders. I don't understand why is the shooting mechanism not working? I had searched Google for making the mechanism

Code:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
player1 = pygame.image.load('player1.png')
player2 = pygame.image.load('player2.png')
bullet1 = pygame.image.load('bullet1.png')
bullet2 = pygame.image.load('bullet2.png')
bullets = []

p1x = 300
p2x = 300

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                if p1x <= 490:
                    p1x += 20
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if p1x > 0:
                    p1x -= 20
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                if p2x > 0:
                    p2x -= 20
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                if p2x <= 490:
                    p2x += 20
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                bullets.append(['d', p1x, 0])
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                bullets.append(['u', p2x, 0])
    for bi in bullets:
        if bi[0] == 'd':
            window.blit(bullet2, (bi[1], bi[2]))
        if bi[0] == 'u':
            window.blit(bullet1, (bi[1], bi[2]))
    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    window.blit(player1, (p2x, 488))
    window.blit(player2, (p1x, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    for bj in bullets:
        if bj[0] == 'd':
                bj[2] += 1
        if bj[0] == 'u':
            bj[2] -= 1
```

[Window's Image][1]

Thanks in advance.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRvZr.png

Answer (score 0):

You have to draw the bullets after clearing the display:

```py
while True:
    # [...]

    window.fill((0, 0, 0))  # <--- INSERT

    for bi in bullets:
        if bi[0] == 'd':
            window.blit(bullet2, (bi[1], bi[2]))
        if bi[0] == 'u':
            window.blit(bullet1, (bi[1], bi[2]))
    
    # window.fill((0, 0, 0)) <--- DELETE

    # [...]
```